# Which file in go-ethereum contains Account type?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts

There is this part of Ethereum whitepaper which describes accounts:

```
An Ethereum account contains four fields:
- The nonce, a counter used to make sure each transaction can only be processed once
- The account's current ether balance
- The account's contract code, if present
- The account's storage (empty by default)
```

It sounds like an Account is a type/structure so I wanted to find it in Ethereum implementation but I am struggling to do so.
I have found *Account* struct in *accounts.go* file in *accounts* package.
This struct contains only Address and URL. So all four "fields" mentioned in the whitepaper are missing.
Am I looking in the wrong place or is whitepaper not fully consistent with the actual code?

Answer (score 2):

[accounts.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/accounts/accounts.go) that you mention is for the user account management (think wallet software) on the Geth node like opening a wallet, closing a wallet, signing a transaction and so on.

For the actual account model implementation, including nonce, balance, code, storage look into [state](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/4c15d58007422069794cada5e38ec8b90940a969/core/state) — [statedb.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/4c15d58007422069794cada5e38ec8b90940a969/core/state/statedb.go) and [state_object.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/4c15d58007422069794cada5e38ec8b90940a969/core/state/state_object.go) in particular.

Comment: It seems statedb.go uses StateAccount struct (package: types, file: state_account.go)